# problem requiring proof by definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am solving real analysis where the author has directly used the below :-

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n} = l \qquad , x_n > 0 \; \forall \;n \in \mathbb{N} $$
then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\log {x_n} = log \;l}$$

I am trying to prove the above by using the standard definition of limits .Here's my approach -

$$since , \;\: x_n > 0 \;\;\forall \;n \in \;\mathbb{N} \Rightarrow l \; \geqslant 0 $$
$$by\;definition\;of\;limits\;,|x_n-l| < \epsilon \;\forall\; n \in \mathbb{N}$$
We need to prove -
$$|\log x_n - \log l| \lt \epsilon \;\forall\; n\;\in \;\mathbb{N} $$
$$\equiv \qquad\qquad|log \frac{x_n}{l}|\; \lt \epsilon \; \forall \;n \; \in \;\mathbb{N}$$
$$\equiv \qquad\qquad -\epsilon\lt log \frac{x_n}{l} \lt \epsilon \;\forall\;n\in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\equiv \qquad\qquad e^{-\epsilon}\lt \frac{x_n}{l}\lt e^{\epsilon} \; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\equiv \qquad\qquad le^{-\epsilon}\lt x_n\lt le^{\epsilon} \; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$

$$since , x_n \lt l + \epsilon \;and \;l + \epsilon \lt le^{\epsilon}\; by \;expamsion \;of \;exponential\;series$$

$$Hence, x_n \lt le^{\epsilon}$$

But i am unable to prove the left inequality i.e.
$$le^{-\epsilon}\lt x_n$$

Any help in this regard or any other approaches is appreciated.

Comment: Tactical advice: don't call a problem "trivial", especially if you can't solve it. Not many dream of wasting their time on a trivial problem (I certainly don't).

Comment: @ProfessorVector edited, thanks !

Comment: Doesn't $\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n} = l $ mean that $\frac {x_{n}}{l}$ gets arbitrarily close to $1$ for large enough $n$? Then  $ e^{-\epsilon}\lt \frac{x_n}{l}\lt e^{\epsilon} $ is satisfied.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n} = l $ means that there exists some natural number k such that n >= k ,all $x_n$ lies in the neighbourhood of k $\forall$ values of $\epsilon$

Comment: This works for any continuous function not only for logarithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties

Comment: @Raffaele while finding limit of a sequence , can we do this trick .While calculating limits of functions which are continuous in nature, sometimes we need to take the log of the limit value , calculate the limit and then reverse back by taking exponent. Can we do the same for sequences also, considering the fact sequences are NOT same as functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your definition of a limit of a sequence is slightly off.

The definition says $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists a natural number N, such that if $n \ge N$ then $|x_n-l|<\epsilon$

So as you showed in the preliminary work... if we want,

$|\log x_n - \log l| \lt \epsilon$,

then that means

$$le^{-\epsilon}\lt x_n\lt le^{\epsilon}$$

$$\iff le^{-\epsilon}-l\lt x_n-l\lt le^{\epsilon}-l$$

Note that $le^{-\epsilon}-l<0$ and $le^{\epsilon}-l>0$

So we choose an $\epsilon_2 = \min\{l-le^{-\epsilon},le^{\epsilon}-l\}$.

Now you can do the actual proof. Given an $\epsilon>0$ you need to show there exists a natural number N such that if $n \ge N$, $|\log x_n - \log l| \lt \epsilon$.

We let $\epsilon_2 = \min\{l-le^{-\epsilon},le^{\epsilon}-l\}$.

Since we are given that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}x_n = l$, we know there's a natural number N such that if $n\ge N$, $|x_n - l|\lt \epsilon_2$

So we need to prove from $|x_n-l|<\epsilon_2$ that $|\log x_n - \log l| \lt \epsilon$. This is essentially going backwards in your derivation.

$|x_n-l|<\epsilon_2 \implies$

$|x_n-l|<l-le^{-\epsilon}$ and $|x_n-l|<le^{\epsilon}-l$

So

$le^{-\epsilon}-l<x_n-l<l-le^{-\epsilon}$

and

$l-le^{\epsilon}<x_n-l<le^{\epsilon}-l$

From these two, we can recover:

$le^{-\epsilon}-l\lt x_n-l\lt le^{\epsilon}-l \implies$

$le^{-\epsilon}\lt x_n\lt le^{\epsilon}$

And so on... keep going backwards to recover $|\log x_n - \log l| \lt \epsilon$

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks !!